# R make install of 3.4.1 on unix is failing test reg-tests-1d

Tags: r

I'm trying to install R on Unix with the following commands:

```
./configure \
  --prefix=${BUILD_PREFIX} \
  --enable-R-shlib \
  --without-x \
  --with-cairo \
  --with-libpng \
  --with-libtiff \
  --with-jpeglib
make
make check
make install
```

And this works all well and fine with R <= 3.3.3 but when I try to build with 3.4.0 or above (.1 or the .2 pre-release) I get the following error:

```
running regression tests ...
make[3]: Entering directory `/code/z-R/R-3.4.1/tests'
running code in 'array-subset.R' ... OK
running code in 'reg-tests-1a.R' ... OK
running code in 'reg-tests-1b.R' ... OK
running code in 'reg-tests-1c.R' ... OK
make[3]: *** [reg-tests-1d.Rout] Error 1
make[2]: *** [test-Reg] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/code/z-R/R-3.4.1/tests'
make[1]: *** [test-all-basics] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/code/z-R/R-3.4.1/tests'
```

Any ideas on what I can do to resolve?

Comment: Post a message with a bit more detail (what results did you get, how could your build be possibly different, ...) to the r-devel list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same problem with R 3.4.0 and 3.4.3.  The fix is to have TZ set in the environment so Sys.timezone() returns a usable value.  I did this with ...

```
    export TZ=`date +%Z`
```

before the 'make check'.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this error on RHEL 8 building R 3.6.1 from source. I can confirm that setting this environment variable will cause the build checks to pass:

```
export TZ="America/New_York"
```

Note that the DRP's recommendation of `date +%Z` does not work with the 3.6 unit tests.